# b-form-input how to modify/format input with @blur in bootstrap-vue table cell?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

Im trying to build an input field with bootstrap-vue,  in which the user can input any desired number and it should be formatted to a decimal number with 3 places.

This is what I've got so far. The focusOut-Method alerts my desired value, but I have no idea how to update the value in the table row with it, as it is called by value. Do you have any idea?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields" >
      <template v-slot:cell(price)="row">
          <b-form-input 
            v-model="row.item.price"
            @blur="focusOut($event, row.item.price)"
          />
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      fields: [...],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    items: function () {
      return [{price: 3.9}, {price: 5}, {price: 9.333}];
    },
  },
  methods: {
    focusOut: function (event, value) {
      if (["Arrow", "Backspace", "Shift"].includes(event.key)) {
        this.preventNextIteration = true;
        return;
      }
      if (this.preventNextIteration) {
        this.preventNextIteration = false;
        return;
      }

      value = parseFloat(value.replace(",", ".")).toLocaleString(undefined, {
        minimumFractionDigits: 3,
      });
      alert(value);
    },
  } ....
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `items` should be a simple data property not a computed one (because you're not doing any calculations), second, Try to get the row index and the cell name (in this case is `price`) then inside the method update the cell at the given row index :

```
   <template v-slot:cell(price)="row">
          <b-form-input 
            v-model="row.item.price"
            @blur="focusOut($event, row.item.price,'price',row.index)"
          />
      </template>
```

```
data: function () {
    return {
      fields: [...],
      items:  [{price: 3.9}, {price: 5}, {price: 9.333}]
    };
  },
```

```
  methods: {
    focusOut: function (event, value,field,index) {
    ... 
  let _value = parseFloat(value.replace(",", ".")).toLocaleString(undefined, {
        minimumFractionDigits: 3,
      });
 //update the field at the given index
  this.$set(this.items,
              index,
                {...this.items[index],[field]:_value})//field represents price
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-feather-ek82e?file=/App.vue)**

Comment: Thank you, I tried that and it updates the value in my items-object fine. But the new value isn't shown in the b-form-input. Is there a way to update it along?

Comment: did you try it out with last answer edit? please check https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-feather-ek82e?file=/App.vue

Comment: your examples does what I want to achieve, so it must be something in the code I left out. I will try to figure that out. Thanks again for your effort!